# Is there a way to create a certificate without CA (multi-account registration) with cdk?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-iot, aws-cdk

I understood the way to create a certificate through the AWS console. But is it possible to do that by CDK (java\python)?

Comment: Do you mean a self-signed certificate (the CA is itself)?

Comment: @OrangeDog no, multi-account registration does not require the user to register a Certificate Authority with AWS.

Comment: I'm guessing not, as [it's not mentioned here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/device-certs-create.html).

Comment: What do you mean by multi account registration?

Comment: @RodrigoM https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/04/simplify-iot-device-registration-and-easily-move-devices-between-aws-accounts-with-aws-iot-core-multi-account-registration/

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. I don't use the CDK, but I create IoT certificates via CLI and by Lambda NodeJS using the AWS SDK. This means AWS exposes an API to create these certs. So logically the CDK can also call that API.

Also note that the CDK, is closely related to CloudFormation. In fact, CDK synthesizes to CloudFormation. You still leverage all the capabilities and resources of CloudFormation by adopting CDK.

So, all this means if you can do it via CLI or Cloudformation, you can likely do it via CDK.

Here is the Python reference https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_iot/CfnCertificate.html

And this is the Java implementation
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/java/index.html?software/amazon/awscdk/services/iot/package-summary.html